# Can't reach Windows Recovery Environment from BIOS

Tags: windows-10

Windows10 on my Dell Precision T3620 is somehow broken, the loading process stops after Dell logo and displays just empty grey screen with blinking mouse arrow (means: no Windows logo appears).

I'm trying to recovery OS from the Dell's own recovery partition - but fail on it too.

Going into BIOS (<kbd>F12</kbd> on my machine) i see all usual BIOS management options and socalled `Windows boot manager` - where should be in my understanding the option to recovery the OS. But, after select `Windows boot manager` i see the grey screen and blinking mouse again.

Changing the boot mode from UEFI into Legacy, i see after selecting `Windows boot manager` Windows logo appearing for the very short time - but then the grey screen again.

I haven't a recovery medium from Dell.

**Q**: what options to run the OS recovery exist, which could help in my case?

Comment: "what options to run the OS recovery exist" - It does not appear like you have a WinRE partition.  Which means the only way to run it is by booting to an installation media.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you suspect BIOS corruption, you might reset the BIOS to default values.

Otherwise, as Windows will not boot, you need to boot from external media.

If you have previously create a Recovery media via Windows Recovery Media Creator,
then use it for repairing the computer by using Startup Repair.

Otherwise, you will need on another computer to download a Windows 10 boot ISO,
write it to USB, and boot in order to do Startup Repair.
Hopefully, a more drastic action won't be necessary.

For details, see the article
[How to Run a Startup Repair in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: no, BIOS seems to be OK - i've run some tests, available at BIOS GUI, they were all unsuspicious. Do you mean, i have no chance to run recovery from the recovery partition? I would like to avoid the creation of external recovery medium - or do it at the very last, if really nothing more could be done.

Comment: Recovery is not run from the BIOS, but rather the BIOS launches the program from the Windows Recovery partition. You may search for it in the BIOS boot menu (usually F12) or try hitting F8 during the boot. But if you can't access it, then an external media is the only way.

Comment: exactly, yes: i see this option in BIOS, but launching it disembogues in the empty grey screen again. Looks, there is no way around external medium, grrr... Thank you for advice!

Comment: I hope your disk has no problem. If you cannot do startup repair, you might consider booting a live Linux CD/USB to save your data before employing stronger measures,